# Error when sending email via Java Mail API?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I got following error when trying to send email via Java Mail API? What does this error mean?

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

Here is my code, i set all parameters (from, to , subjects and attachments)

```
public static void send(MailUtil mailUtil) throws MessagingException {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            if (props.getProperty(IConstants.DL_MAIL_CONFIGURATION.MAIL_SENDER) != null) {              
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(props.getProperty(IConstants.DL_MAIL_CONFIGURATION.MAIL_SENDER)));
            } else {
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailUtil.getFrom()));
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(mailUtil.getTo()));
            if (mailUtil.getBcc() != null && mailUtil.getBcc().trim().length() > 0) {
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(mailUtil.getBcc()));
            } else {
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,InternetAddress.parse(""));
            }

            message.setSubject(mailUtil.getSubject(), "UTF-8");

            // Check for files list and attach them.
            if (mailUtil.attachmentFiles != null && mailUtil.attachmentFiles.size() > 0) {
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

                // Set content.
                BodyPart messageBodyPart =new MimeBodyPart();
                messageBodyPart.setContent(mailUtil.getContent(), "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                // Attach files.
                for (File file : mailUtil.attachmentFiles) {
                    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
                    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                }

                message.setContent(multipart);
            } else {
                //message.setContent("<h1>Hello world</h1>", "text/html");
                message.setContent(mailUtil.getContent(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            }           
            Transport.send(message);
    }
```

I just think is there any problem with my paramters?

Belows is my configuration

```
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.timeout=25000

mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.username = username@gmail.com
mail.password = mypassword
mail.sender = sender@gmail.com
mail.receiver = receiver@gmail.com
mail.subject = mysubject
```

I am using google mail server! I dont' think there is problem there!

Belows is session initiation

```
final String userName = props.getProperty(IConstants.DL_MAIL_CONFIGURATION.MAIL_USERNAME);
final String passWord = props.getProperty(IConstants.DL_MAIL_CONFIGURATION.MAIL_PASSWORD);

session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName,
                                passWord);
                    }
            });
```

Comment: Please share code as well without it hard to help you

Comment: You need the information about MessageingException check with url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659325/getting-javax-mail-messagingexception-and-java-net-socketexception

Comment: There's a time out there, so probably your email server is either unreachable or the properties setup is not correct.

Comment: I am using google mail server. I dont think having problem there. I tried to telnet smtp.gmail.com 465. It's reachable

Comment: Could you post your Session instantiation?

Comment: I just posted it, please see

Comment: And the props setup :D

Comment: It already stay above

Comment: Are you sure you have good internet connection?

Comment: Are you connecting to the internet via proxy?

Comment: yes, internet connection is good. What could proxy affects? It seems that my mail client could not receive acknowledgement from mail server

Comment: Nope, I don't see the props object instantiation, I'm talking about the one passing as a parameter to Session.getDefaultInstance

Comment: mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.timeout=25000

mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.username = username@gmail.com
mail.password = mypassword
mail.sender = sender@gmail.com
mail.receiver = receiver@gmail.com
mail.subject = mysubject

Comment: Please check this one

Comment: Still, not the object been passed as parameter to Session.getDefaultInstance

Comment: The content of properties file I have posted above. Which property in its content do you expect or think it should emerge?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the mail object you keep referring to, it's not the one been passed to Session.getDefaultInstance, I don't see the code where you assign the properties from the mail object to the props object, do you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83884/discussion-between-chin-nghe-and-typo).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it absolutely relates to server configuration.
When I change the port configuration from 465 to 587, it solves my problem!
Anyway, thank you guy for your help!

Comment: Correct,  Port 465 expects you to start an SSL session and then run smtp over it, compared to port 587 where the session begins in plaintext SMTP, and then starttls is used to negotiate an encrypted TLS session.  So, the first two lines of your config are in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you use a "mail" object to setup the connection properties, instead try this, it should work, I've tested myself:

```
private Properties props;
props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 

session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });
try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("RECEIVER EMAIL ADDRESS HERE"));
        message.setSubject("SUBJECT");

        message.setText("THE EMAIL TEXT");
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and configuration contain many of these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  In particular, the use of [Session.getDefaultInstance may mean you're not using the configuration you think you're using](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance).  If fixing that doesn't solve your problem, post the [JavaMail session debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).