# Exception while sending mail, java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Good day.
I'm trying to rewrite our code to send mail with ssl authentication. Because our system administrators added to postfix agent auth. In hosts on linux machine there are server name for smtp server and ip. I checked the connection with telnet.

So, here my code which are creating properties and session.

```
private Properties createProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", OurSTMPHostServer);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //SSL Port
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); //SSL Port
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",  "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", MAIL_USER);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", MAIL_PASSWORD);
    return properties;
}

private Session createSession(Properties properties) {
    Session session =  Session.getInstance(properties,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication
                getPasswordAuthentication() { return new PasswordAuthentication(MAIL_USER, MAIL_PASSWORD); }
            });
    session.setDebug(true);
    return session;
}
```

Here the code creating message

```
public MimeMessage createMimeMessage(String mailFromAddress, String mailFromName,
                                     String subject, String mailTo, String message, String messageText, List<File> fileList) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(createSession(createProperties()));
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFromAddress, mailFromName));
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, mailTo);
    MimeBodyPart wrap = new MimeBodyPart();
    MimeMultipart cover = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
    MimeBodyPart text = new MimeBodyPart();
    text.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
    text.setContent(messageText, "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    cover.addBodyPart(text);
    MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
    html.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
    html.setContent(message, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    cover.addBodyPart(html);
    wrap.setContent(cover);
    MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart("related");
    msg.setContent(content);
    content.addBodyPart(wrap);
    msg.saveChanges();
    return msg;
}
```

Here the code for sending message

```
public void sendTextMessage(String mailFromAddress, @Nullable String mailFromName, String subject, String mailTo, String message) {
    MimeMessage msg = null;
    try {
        String messageText = convertService.htmlToText(message);
        msg = createMimeMessage(mailFromAddress, mailFromName, subject, mailTo, message, messageText, Collections.<File>emptyList());
            mailSenderFacade.send(msg);
    }
}
```

Where mailSenderFacade is JavaMailSender class where field host = OurSMTPHostServer, port = 465
UPD:
here the error

```
<pre>org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1611)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
    at com.zina.service.mail.MailSenderFacade.send(MailSenderFacade.java:122)
    at com.zina.service.mail.MailService.sendTextMessage(MailService.java:131)
    at com.zina.service.mail.MailService.sendTextMessage(MailService.java:193)
    at com.zina.service.person.PersonService.sendRegistrationApproveMail(PersonService.java:255)
    at com.zina.service.person.PersonService.registerUser_aroundBody4(PersonService.java:167)
    at com.zina.service.person.PersonService$AjcClosure5.run(PersonService.java:1)
</pre>
```

Comment: How about sharing the Exception?

Comment: What is the exact `Exception` and at which line is it thrown?

Comment: Added exception

Comment: Is the use of two different SMPT ports intentional and on purpose? I don't know if that is a or the problem, but I haven't seen that before. Instead, code I know uses the same port for `"mail.smtp.port"` and `"mail.smtp.socketFactory.port"`.

Comment: @deHaar
Are you talking about lines?
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //SSL Port
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); //SSL 
I found this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553594/4137384
And was thinking that this will help
But the code where all ports are 465 are't working either.

Comment: @Yan Yes, those are the lines... It was just something I noticed in your code, which might have been a problem. Have you tried the other port, too? I mean 567 in both lines? Is SMPTS used, now the authentication has changed?

Comment: @deHaar Change everywhere port for 587 in java code and in properties for JavaMailSender and got new error
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 4.7.1 <test3-www>: Helo command rejected: Host not found

Comment: OK, then it's definitely wrong to do so ;-)

Comment: Try to Change `properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");` to `properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");` (or better remove the line for `port: 587`) see one article here, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sending-email-java-ssltls-authentication/ might be helpful. SSL auth Mail Send is in bottom example.

Comment: when u mean u tried the connection with telnet ? what exactly did u tried? Also the fact that telnet works does not mean that in reality u can communicate. Could u try also with an SMTP cli client?

Comment: @miiiii
Set the property properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465"); //SSL Port
And in properties email.port=465
Now i've got
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: @AntJavaDev
I connected with thunderbird to stmp using:
port - 465
connection security - ssl/tls
auth method - encrypted password
serverName - ourServerName

Comment: Why the 2 different properties for ?? `mail.smtp.port` and `email.port` ?? (from you last comment).

Comment: are u sure the host is being defined properly ? or maybe is there any other configuration that might be blocking those connections? The thunderbird app is hosted within the same machine that u are trying to run that java app?

Comment: You can read this FAQ.. very simple, detailed and intuitive... there are questions and answers related to yours.. https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes

Comment: I was able to send message using ssmtp, properties:
root=robot@ourDomain
mailhub=ourSMPTServer:465
rewriteDomain=ourDomain
AuthUser=robot@ourDomain
AuthPass=password
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES